# Vacuum decay in QFT (flat spacetime): Help me

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, field-theory, higgs

I start explaining my doubt from the properties of the vacuum: the vacuum is a quantum state $|0>$ of minimum energy for which the vacuum expectation value of our (scalar) field $<\phi>_{VEV}=\bar{\phi}$ is at the minimum of the potential. If the potential has two non degenerate minimum (like the one in figure), this means the presence of two different vacuum states $|0>_{f,t}$ for which the field has two different VEV: the false and the true vacuum. The false vacuum $|0>_{f}$ can decay to the true vacuum $|0>_{t}$. The vacuum decay rate depends on the solution  of the classical euclidean field equation,  $\phi(\rho)$, that has an O(4) symmetry. This solution is a bubble with the classical scalar field equal to the true VEV inside and to the false one outside and some values in the interface zone.
What is the meaning of this classical field solution? Why can we infer from it that inside we are in true vacuum and outside in false vacuum?

[image]